Mypy doesn't consider the if condition
I have a dictionary with different types, and in my code, while reading the dictionary through a loop, based on the type of it, I have different operations. The code is working as expected, but MYPY is complaining that it is incorrect. Here is the sample code:
COL = {
    "ABC": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
    ],
    "BBC": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
    ],
    "XYZ": {
        "col1": "c1",
        "col2": "c2",
        "col3": "c3",
    },
}
for table_name in COL:
    list(COL[table_name].keys()) if 
    isinstance(COL[table_name], dict) else 
    COL[table_name]

Mypy reports the error: error: "Collection[str]" has no attribute "values"
It looks like the if condition was not taken into consideration.
Tried type annotations for COL but did not work.

What is table_name? Are you sure the error is about values and not rather keys?

The table names are ABC, BBC, XYZ in this case and they are passed dynamically through loop

Just for the sake of simplicity: dict[str, _] is an Iterable[str] - you can just use for table_name in COL: list(COL[table_name]) to get either the list, if it was already there, or a list of dict's keys. You need dict.keys only on rare occasions in python 3 - usually to do set arithmetics on them. If you loop over those (list comprehension, for example), you don't even need list() - just use whatever you got.

Mypy reports an error because it is unsure whether COL[table_name] will be the same in both accesses.
This is not a specific problem to Mypy. To quote Eric Traut (the primary maintainer of Pyright) from issue 11534:

Type narrowing for dynamic subscript expressions is very difficult to implement because it requires the type checker to ensure that the value of the expression found within the type guard test evaluates the same value as the expression found within the guarded block. That's difficult to do when the expression is dynamic. [...]

If an intermediate variable is introduced, there will be no error:
(playground)
list(table.keys()) if isinstance(table := COL[table_name], dict) else table  # fine


Extract a variable to show to mypy that the expression COL[table_name] always refers to the same object:
col = COL[table_name]
list(col.keys()) if isinstance(col, dict) else col

